# highcharts not sure how to load data from external json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I have not been able to import my JSON in any way, I am very new to JS so might be a really dumb issue. Anyway, my complete code is from an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <title>Highcharts Example</title>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
   var chart;
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {

     chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
       renderTo: 'container',
       type: 'line',
       marginRight: 130,
       marginBottom: 25
      },
      title: {
       text: 'Revenue vs. Overhead',
       x: -20 //center
      },
      subtitle: {
       text: '',
       x: -20
      },
      xAxis: {
       categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
      },
      yAxis: {
       title: {
        text: 'Amount'
       },
       plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 1,
        color: '#808080'
       }]
      },
      tooltip: {
       formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
         this.x + ': ' + this.y;
       }
      },
      legend: {
       layout: 'vertical',
       align: 'right',
       verticalAlign: 'top',
       x: -10,
       y: 100,
       borderWidth: 0
      },
      series: json
     });
    });

   });

  });
 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

 <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

It works if the data.php is formatted as it is in example: `[{ "name": "Revenue", "data": [23987, 24784, 25899, 25569, 25897, 25668, 24114, 23899, 24987, 25111, 25899, 23221] }, { "name": "Overhead", "data": [21990, 22365, 21987, 22369, 22558, 22987, 23521, 23003, 22756, 23112, 22987, 22897] }]` However, I am creating JSON via json_encode by making an SQL query so my data.php is actually like this: `[{"id":"1","time":"12.00"},{"id":"2","time":"13.00"}]`

However, I am creating JSON via json_encode by making an SQL query so my data.php is actually like this:

```
[{"id":"1","time":"12.00"},{"id":"2","time":"13.00"}]
```

Basically, I need Y axis to be "id" and x axis "time".

I've tried so many times, but I cannot even get the chart to load. Is the way my JSON is formatted completely off or is there a way to make it work ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to create a format function to convert your data to expected format:

```
const format = (arr) => {
  let ids = arr.map((item) => {
    return Number(item.id);
  });
  let times = arr.map((item) => {
    return item.time;
  });
  return {
      ids,
      times
  };
}
```

For example:

```
let data = [{"id":"1","time":"12.00"},{"id":"2","time":"13.00"}];
let json = format(data);
// json = {ids: [Array of IDs], times: [Array of times]}
```

Then you can use json data to pass through Highcharts.Chart:

```
...
xAxis: {
  categories: json.times
},
...
series: [{name: 'IDs', data: json.ids}]
```

I've tested and got something like below:

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! It will take a while for me to get it going, but now at least I have a direction.

Comment: Any chance you could send me the full code ? I still seem to have trouble... especially parsing the json with jquery